# How to handle too many elements in django-ajax-select admin panel?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-admin, django-ajax-selects

I am using the `django-ajax-select` library to display a many to many relationship in the admin panel. The problem is that I have too many objects linked and it is making super long page.

Do you know if is there any way I can customize that element so it can have some kind of scrollbar or pagination?

Here is an example illustrating the problem:
[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pzzK.png)

And this is how I added the element to the admin panel:

```py
form = make_ajax_form(
    MainClass,
    {
        "users": "user", # LookupChannel is registered as user
        "admins": "user",
    },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

answer is on the first page of the django-ajax-select

https://django-ajax-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

you should override get_query like this:

```
def get_query(self, q, request):
        return super().get_query(q, request)[your_search_limit]
```

your_search_limit - the length of the list you want to get.